# How to swap elements in ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>?

Tags: java, arraylist, swap

I'm trying to swap elements in `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>`. I wanted to know either an inbuilt function if present any or brute-force approach to solve :
`swap(mat.get(i).get(j),mat.get(j).get(i+1))` 
swapping these 2 elements in a `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>`.

Comment: There is [`Collections.swap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#swap(java.util.List,int,int)) to swap two elements in a list. However, you will not find an in-built function to swap elements of two different lists. Just store the two elements in local variables, and use [`List.set()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#set(int,E)) to assign them where they belong.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a built-in function to swap these two elements.

A brute force solution would have to store one value in another variable and then swap them in O(1) time.

Something like:

```
void swap(int i, int j){
    int val = bigList.get(i).set(j, bigList.get(i+1).get(j));
    bigList.get(i+1).set(j, val);
}
```

--Where 'bigList' is the parent ArrayList containing ArrayLists.

Hope this helps!